# parent.document.getElementById and images path

Tags: javascript, php, html

first of all, sorry for my poor english. I have a problem with a js file which load an HTML file in an iframe. It's something like this:

```
parent.document.getElementById("iframe1").src = '../blablabla.php?id='+id;
```

And that php file includes the HTML file, so I load it in the content iframe. My problem is that the HTML has images with a relative path and they are not shown because of the incorrect path. Is there any way to change the path without changing the HTML?

Comment: It seems Ajax is the key to your problems..

Comment: An `iframe` loads an entire html page and you should not try to fix a wrong path of that loaded page in the page that contains the `iframe`, but in the page you load. So you need to fix the problem in the `blablabla.php` file, just open the `blablabla.php`  directly in your browser, check the paths and correct the relative paths so that it the images are displayed correctly.

Comment: Thanks everybody, I solved it adding <base href> in the blablabla.php before the code that includes the HTML file. Now I have an HTML with 2 <head> but it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to be sure:
You can't access the specific html pages? 
If you can: What is the reason why you don't use a base url?

```
<head>
    <base href="base url here">
</head>
```

Comment: won't work. OP is embedding the html in some other page, which means the embedded content inherits the container's base

Comment: If he has access to the HTML, he can try to replace the paths with PHP and pass the path over an parameter.

Comment: @MarcB
Thank you! I misunderstood the example. I was confused by changing the "src" value on an element with id "div1". 
With that in mind i even wonder why he isn't using an absolute path in the string he is setting the value to.